# Scala Iterator.takeWhile is dropping the failed element

Tags: scala, iterator

```
val i = (1 to 8).toIterator
val oneToThree = i.takeWhile(_ <= 3).toList
// List(1, 2, 3)
```

So far so good.
Now I want the iterator to still contain `(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)`, but if I carry on:

```
val fourToSix = i.takeWhile(_ <= 6).toList
// List(5, 6)
```

Element 3 has gone missing. I would preferably like `fourToSix` to be `List(4, 5, 6)`. How can I use `takeWhile` or some similar operation so that this works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the documentation on `takeWhile` states:

> Reuse: After calling this method, one should discard the iterator it
>   was called on, and use only the iterator that was returned. Using the
>   old iterator is undefined, subject to change, and may result in
>   changes to the new iterator as well.

So you shouldn't use `i`, after calling `takeWhile` on it.

---

But to achieve what you want you can use the `span` method:

```
scala> val i = (1 to 8).iterator
i: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> val (oneToThree, rest) = i.span(_ <= 3)
oneToThree: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
rest: Iterator[Int] = unknown-if-empty iterator

scala> oneToThree.toList
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val fourToSix = rest.takeWhile(_ <= 6)
fourToSix: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> fourToSix.toList
res2: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: So I'm writing a class that extends Iterator. I have an internal iterator (similar to `i` in this example) and I'm calling `i.takeWhile` in my overridden `next()`... would it be bad practice to have `i` as a `var` that I can update to `rest` after calling span?

Comment: Looks reassigning to `var` won't work, I have an ever-growing stack of iterators and calling `next` is getting progressively slower.

Comment: @Tom Actually, in that case I'd recommend to try and implement `takeWhile` yourself using `hasNext` and `next`. The real reason your code in the question doesn't work is that after taking an element from the iterator you can't put it back into the iterator, and there is no interface to "peek" the next element. So you'd have to maintain an internal var with an optional current element and put the element failing the predicate into it. It's hard to give a more detailed answer without more info, so if this manual implementation doesn't work you may consider asking another, more general question.